# Can't log into Docker hub from terminal due to Error response from daemon: Get "https://auth/v2/": dial tcp: lookup auth: no such host?

Tags: docker, authentication

I have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 lts setup which has now docker installed on it after getting errors regarding too many requests I tried to log into dockerhub using :

```
docker login auth
```

I provide the same credentials that allowed me to log into their website and then I get this:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://auth/v2/": dial tcp: lookup auth: no such host
```

I have added  google and cloudflare DNS to my routers DHCP settings so all lan members should have google as their DNS provider as well as the local one that functions.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the command is

```
docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
```

Since there is no `auth` option, it tries to log you into a registry at the server address `auth`.

If you want to login to Docker Hub, the command is just

```
docker login
```

Please note that `docker login` logs you into a docker registry. From your post, I'm not sure that's what you want to do or if you're having trouble logging into the local machine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the registry issue. I had just copied the command from the web :D